# Use of wide chars leading to memory access exceptions in RAD Studio C++Builder

Tags: c++, exception, memory, access-violation, c++builder-xe3

So I have been playing around with chars and wide chars in a basic program that recursively scans directories in Windows. Initially I was using standard chars and strings, as well as some related functions for accomplishing this task (FindFirstFile, FindNextFile, etc.) The actual recursion is passed on to a created thread via CreateThread and WaitForSingleObject; which worked completely fine and as expected.

However, an issue arose when I converted those chars, strings, and related functions to their wide counterparts (wchar_t, wstring, FindFirstFileW, etc.) Now the program is throwing an exception when recursively scanning directories with more than a small number of folders/files. The exception is occurring during the WaitForSingleObject phase of my thread handling. I have [tracked down the following info](http://docs.embarcadero.com/products/rad_studio/delphiAndcpp2009/HelpUpdate2/EN/html/delphivclwin32/SysUtils_EAccessViolation.html) on the exception itself:

> **EAccessViolation** is the exception class for invalid memory access
>   errors.
>
> EAccessViolation is raised when an application:
>
> *Dereferences a nil (Delphi) or NULL (C++) pointer.*
>
> *Writes to memory reserved for executable code.*
>
> *Attempts to access a memory address for which there is no virtual
>   memory allocated to the application.*
>
> Run-time exception information is saved in fields provided by
>   EExternal.
>
> Note: Applications should not raise EAccessViolation
>   directly, but should instead rely on the runtime to raise this
>   exception.

My question is, why on earth would this exception be thrown when the only thing I have changed is the type of characters being used? The IDE I am using is RAD Studio XE3 C++Builder and unfortunately, I can't really test this on one of my other IDEs without making significant changes to the code.

Comment: You're asking for speculation?  EAccessViolation can happen when your code misinterprets the size of your data.  And converting to wide characters changes the size of your data.  Your conversion was probably incomplete.

Comment: One important difference is that with narrow strings (`char`) the number of characters is also the number of bytes. Wide strings are different, they use more bytes than the number of characters.

Comment: @DrewDormann Speculations, educated guesses, anything that can help shed some light on this for me. I'm a java programmer by trade and am still noobish with C++. Character encoding is what I'm mainly struggling with. I'll reevaluate my conversions.

Comment: @b1naryatr0phy Also if any code expects a string to end with a null `wchar`, an accidental `char` string could cause that code to go *far* out of bounds.  The short answer is that a correct conversion to `wchar` will not cause these exceptions, but converting the code *correctly* isn't necessarily trivial.  You likely have some remaining code that's using `char[]` strings or expecting string length to equal byte length.

Comment: @DrewDormann Thanks for the info Drew, that is definitely helpful. I should probably go read some of the other fundamentals of handling the various types of chars and strings. My 1600 page textbook doesn't even begin to cover that subject =/

Comment: You have an error in your code.